# Unity iOS app's screen goes black on startup, but still appears to be running

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, screen

I'm using Unity Pro 4.5.3f3 + iOS Pro 4.x, Xcode 5.1.1, and tested with an iPhone 4S and 5 running iOS 7.1.2.

I recently took over development of an iOS app from a departing coworker at my game studio, and I'm attempting to compile the app in Xcode on my own machine for the first time. I have followed his instructions for which extra Obj-C code to add manually. The app works perfectly in Unity. Everything builds in Xcode without errors.

When the app runs, I see the custom splash screen loading as intended, but then the screen goes completely black. The app appears to be running fine...I can hear its sounds playing and it even responds when I tap the screen in areas where I know the buttons are supposed to be. There are no errors thrown to the log. But it doesn't display any graphics at all!

I suspect the Prime[31] plugin has something to do with it, as I get a strange log output saying Prime[31] didn't recognize several other plugins. And I can't delete it to test my theory, because way too many scripts depend on it.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have lots of tasks to do for this app and I can't let something like this slow me down.

Comment: Ok, I just managed to delete Prime[31] from the app without breaking it, and the bug is still there, so I think that plugin is innocent. Anyone else have any ideas on what might cause something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue last night when trying to configure my app to be compatible with Facebook Canvas.

Below is the line of code that was breaking:

```
FB.Canvas.SetAspectRatio(9,16, FBScreen.CenterHorizontal(), FBScreen.CenterVertical());
```

To fix my issue I surrounded the line with the [UNITY_WEBPLAYER](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) preprocessor directive like so:

```
#if UNITY_WEBPLAYER
    FB.Canvas.SetAspectRatio(9,16, FBScreen.CenterHorizontal(), FBScreen.CenterVertical());
#endif
```

Doing this causes that line of code to only be compiled and run in the web player, and not on the mobile device. Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't have support for Canvas in my code. Not sure what was breaking, but for the time being I've reverted to Unity 4.5.2, which doesn't have this problem.